# How to calculate duration in R sequentially

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset that looks like this where patients are intubated (based on ObservationValue of "Start") and extubation (based on ObservationValue of "Stop"). Occasionally there is unfortunately misentries where the patient has an extubation before the intubation, as seen in EncounterID #3 below, where they had an extubation, followed by an intubation. In those instances I have no interest in calculating their ventilation duration. My question therefore is, how can I calculate the **duration in which I subtract the first extubation that happened *after* each intubation?**
My apologies if this is a basic question, I am still fairly new to using R for data management.

Here is an example of my dataset:
[image]

And this is what I would like ideally:
[image]

Here is dput output of the dataset I currently have:

```
test<-structure(list(EncounterID=structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)),
                ObservationDate=structure(c("2018-01-12 15:27:00", "2018-01-12 19:02:00", "2018-03-03 21:09:00", "2018-03-06 07:56:00", 
                                            "2019-12-03 15:54:00", "2019-12-03 20:06:00", "2019-12-04 11:40:00", "2019-12-06 08:13:00",
                                            "2019-12-23 18:50:00", "2019-12-23 16:00:00")),
                ObservationValue=structure(c("Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Stop", "Start"))),
                row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
test$ObservationDate<-as.POSIXct(test[["ObservationDate"]],tz="", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Comment: Your example data doesn’t include any cases where the extubation date is earlier than the intubation date? You say this happens in EncounterID 4, but you only included IDs 1-3. For EncounterID 3, the `"Stop"` row comes before the `"Start"` row, but the associated datetimes are still in the right order.

Comment: Thanks for your observation @zephryl, great catch! Yes, I meant it for Encounter ID 3. Yes, in encounter ID 3, the extubation happened 2 hours and 50 minutes aka "Stop" before intubation aka "Start".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of data wrangling and reshaping to wide format you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test |> 
  arrange(EncounterID, ObservationDate) |> 
  group_by(EncounterID) |> 
  mutate(id = cumsum(ObservationValue == "Start")) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ObservationValue, values_from = ObservationDate) |> 
  rename(Inturbation = Start, Exturbation = Stop) |> 
  mutate(duration = difftime(Exturbation, Inturbation, units = "days"))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   EncounterID    id Inturbation         Exturbation         duration      
#>         <dbl> <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>        
#> 1           1     1 2018-01-12 15:27:00 2018-01-12 19:02:00 0.1493056 days
#> 2           1     2 2018-03-03 21:09:00 2018-03-06 07:56:00 2.4493056 days
#> 3           2     1 2019-12-03 15:54:00 2019-12-03 20:06:00 0.1750000 days
#> 4           2     2 2019-12-04 11:40:00 2019-12-06 08:13:00 1.8562500 days
#> 5           3     1 2019-12-23 16:00:00 2019-12-23 18:50:00 0.1180556 days
```